# Is local storage database the fastest way for temporary browser tasks

Tags: javascript, sql, database, taffydb

I'm creating a website to perform some analytics on data and need to create a database to store the records and do some simple operations upon them. At the moment I'm using [TaffyDB](http://www.taffydb.com/) and the dataset is about 85000 records that without duplicates will be around 3-5000.

Extraction of the insertion code looks like

```
var db_pos = db({date:date_stamp}).first();
if(db_pos.date != undefined) {
    db_pos.count++;
} else {
    db.insert({date:date_stamp, count: 1});
}
```

Since the database will be deleted after the session is over I assume that using server-side databases is unnecessary. What would be the fastest option to check for duplicates over 85000 records and insert 3-5000 unique ones as well as performing operations such as count? At the moment I have a running time of around 10-15 seconds.

Comment: If the majority of your database is duplicates, it may be faster to rebuild it as a new database as you check existance rather than removing duplicates

Comment: @PaulS. would this be efficient even if the count of duplicates is important?